# Is there a slider Widget in Elementor that allows creating a carousel with navigation arrows and numbers indicating the slide?

Tags: wordpress, slider, carousel, elementor

I need a carousel widget similar to the one used on the IBM website, as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzRfX.png). The navigation should include two arrows with the slide number in between them, just like in the screenshot. I have tried various carousel widgets, but none of them have the desired design. If the widget requires additional downloads, that is okay. Thank you.